# How to define InterpolatingFunction on a variable set of points?

Tags: function-construction, interpolation

I would like to define an InterpolatingFunction to which data points are transferred as a parameter, e.g.:

```
h[i_]:=(i-0.5)*12.5;
data={0.0047,0.021,0.023,0.015,0.00085,0.0041,0.0018,0.00077};
f[data_,x_]:=g[x]/.Interpolation[Table[{h[i],data[[i]]},{i,1,Length[data]}]];
Plot[f[data,x],{x,h[1],h[Length[data]]}]
```

or

```
f[data_]:=Interpolation[Table[{h[i],data[[i]]},{i,1,Length[data]}]]
```

However when I’m trying to evaluate or plot function (`Plot[f[data,x],{x,h[1],h[Length[data]]}]`) Mathematica shows the same error in both cases `ReplaceAll::reps: {InterpolatingFunction[…]} is neither a list of replacement rules nor a valid dispatch table, and so cannot be used for replacing.` (By three dots I’ve replaced a set of values and options).
Could you suggest what I’m doing wrong?

In the following I want to use f[data,x] for definition of the objective function and minimize it on various 'data' vectors and at a given set of points 'x' (x1,…, xn).

Comment: Do you mean to only sample `h` at integer steps?

Comment: Can you be more specific about "both do not work"? How don't they work? Does it spit out errors? Can you provide an example `h` and an example `data` set? When you say "minimize it on various `data` vectors  and at a given set of points 'x'", do you mean find the `data` that minimizes `f` at a particular `x` or something else? Please provide more details.

Comment: @march and IPoiler, thanks for your comments, please see the updated OP.

Comment: The error is related to the fact that what you are attempting to use to the right of the `/.` is not valid. The right of the `/.` must be either `Rule`s, `Association`s, or a `Dispatch`. `Interpolation` returns an `InterpolatingFunction` object, which is none of those types, and thus cannot be used with `/.`. You may want to omit the `g[x]/.` in that case and just let `f` be the `InterpolatingFunction`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Functionally, this definition of `f` works the way I think you're trying to describe your needs:

```
f[data_, x_] := Interpolation[Table[{h[i], data[[i]]}, {i, 1, Length[data]}], x];
```

Though, I have reservations about this method with large data vectors because it requires interpolating for every `x` that's plotted. It'd be better to to create the `InterpolatingFunction` once for a data set then plot it.

Comment: Oh, it was that straightforward! Thank you for your help and last comment as well.